# Python - How to perform a tuple unpacking in a class

Tags: python, class, oop

The following code computes the distance and the slope between two coordinates. The tuple unpacking is perform directly in the functions .distance() and .slope(). I would like to perform the tuple unpacking directly in the __init__method. Do you have any idea how to do it? I tried with indexing but probably I did something wrong.

```
class Line():
#We define the variables (attributes of the class)    
    def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
        self.coor1=coor1
        self.coor2=coor2
#We define a function that unpack the tuples and calculates the distance between the points    
    def distance(self):
        x1,y1=self.coor1
        x2,y2=self.coor2
        return ((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)**(1/2)
#We define a function that unpack the tuples and calculate the slope 
    def slope(self):
        x1,y1=self.coor1
        x2,y2=self.coor2
        return (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize (`self.x1`, `self.y1`) and (`self.x2`, `self.y2`) similar to how you defined `self.coor1` and `self.coor2` in your `__init__`. For example:

```
class Line():   
    def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
        #self.coor1 = coor1
        #self.coor2 = coor2
        self.x1, self.y1 = coor1
        self.x2, self.y2 = coor2
    def distance(self):
        return ((self.x2-self.x1)**2+(self.y2-self.y1)**2)**(1/2)
    def slope(self):
        return (self.y2-self.y1)/(self.x2-self.x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list unpacking for defining `(x, y)` cordinates value as

```
class Cord:
    def __init__(self, cord1, cord2):
        self.x1, self.y1 = cord1
        self.x2, self.y2 = cord2
```

Apart from this you can, create a class for points cordinates and the use that class object in the class Line for calculationn. Below is sample code

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        

class Line:
    def __int__(self, cord1, cord2):
        self.cord1 = cord1
        self.cord2 = cord2
    def distance(self):
        return ((self.cord1.x - self.cord2.x)**2 + (self.cord2.y - self.cord2.y)**2)**0.5
    
    def slope(self):
        return (self.cord2.y-self.cord1.y)/(self.cord2.x - self.cord1.x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You added the option to create a class for points coordinates. Really nice!